# While Integrating Google, what does 'Get your backend server's OAuth 2.0 client ID' means?

Tags: android, oauth

I am a new Android Developer & Stack Overflow user so help me with my doubt about Google Integration.

Basically, I am trying to integrate google sign-in in my android application & stuck at step "Get your backend server's OAuth 2.0 client ID",

I am referring [Start Integrating Google Sign-In into Your Android App](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating) link

Any understanding regarding this step will kindly appreciated.

Comment: Check out the following: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating#get_your_backend_servers_oauth_20_client_id

Comment: I am referring that same link, I want to understand that point, What is it & why it is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clearly written on that link. You have to sign up for a OAuth client ID by going to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials and clicking on "Create credentials" and choosing OAuth Client (Also you need a backend server to be able to communicate with google server). You should choose "Web application" as you application type. This gives you a `client_id` and a `client_secret`.

Comment: Thank you but one more help please what is OAuth Client?

Comment: What is oauth? https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749. How to use google oauth? https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

Comment: Okay got it,
Thank you so much :)